# I have an IOS App transferred to my account, what i need from the seller in order for me to update the app myself?

Tags: ios, mobile, certificate, keychain, transfer

Recently I bought an IOS app from a seller. Seller will transfer the ownership to me.

What other important files that I should get from seller in order for me to update the app myself later? Certificate? Keychain?

Comment: You should have maybe thought about that before buying an app...

Comment: You can create all the need certificate for the app you bought in the certificate portal.

Comment: I hope your app doesn't have push notifications because setting up push notification development provision profiles and SSL certificates is a PITA :D If your app is a basic app with no special features then you can regenerate the development certificate and distribution certificate and provision profile using your developer account and continue updating the app from there. Otherwise, if you want to rebuild the app from scratch using your own code, you can do so, as long as the bundle ID for the app in your xcode matches the app store one e.g. com.mycompany.appname in Xcode and iTunes Connect.

Answer (score 0):

All you will need are the provisioning profiles and Development / Distribution Certificates. Then you should be good to go.

Hope that helps :)